# Apple Configurator 2 cannot install an app (has HealthKit capability) to iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipa, healthkit

I have a problem when installing ipa.

My app has Universal setting, and the app uses HealthKit.

(HealthKit only be used by available device.)

I can install it to iOS devices,but I cannot install it to iPad devices.

- This app could run on iPad with "Run"
- With install enterprise ipa by AppleConfigurator 2, it occurred an error.
- I could install it by creating ipa with the HealthKit-Capability removed.
- The iPad is formatted.(No profile and no parental control)

Does anyone have the same problem?
Or, do I need to make some special setting for HealthKit incompatible terminals?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot about requirements(in Info.plist) existence.
The problem was solved.